# Image detection inside an image

Tags: android, opencv

I usually play a game called [Burako](http://www.google.com.ar/images?q=burako&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=es&tab=wi).
It has some color playing pieces with numbers from 1-13.

After a match finishes you have to count your points.
For example:

```
 1 == 15 points
 2 == 20 points
```

I want to create an app that takes a picture and count the pieces for me.
So I need something that recognizes an image inside an image.

I was about to read about `OpenCV` since there is an [Android port](http://github.com/billmccord/OpenCV-Android) but it feels there should be something simpler to do this.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not used the Android port, but i think it's doable under good lighting conditions.

I would obtain the minimal bounding boxes of each of the pieces and rotate it accordingly so you can compare it with a model image.

Another way could be to get the contour of the numbers written on the piece ( which i guess are in color) and do some contour matching with the numbers.

Opencv is a big and complex framework but it's also suitable for simple tasks like this.